# How do I cancel event bubbling in a YUI DataTable?

Tags: javascript, yui, event-bubbling, yui-datatable

I am trying to create a YUI 2.8.1 DataTable with a checkbox column. When the user selects the row it should highlight, but not when the user checks the checkbox.

I'm trying to suppress the rowClickEvent by setting `cancelBubble = true` in the checkboxClickEvent, but the YUI library ignores this. How do I prevent the rowClickEvent from firing?

```
this.testDataTable.subscribe("checkboxClickEvent", function (oArgs)
{
    var elCheckbox = oArgs.target;
    var oRecord = this.getRecord(elCheckbox);
    oRecord.setData("check", elCheckbox.checked);
    oArgs.event.cancelBubble = true; //Event bubbles anyway
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return false from the checkboxClickEvent

Answer (score 0):

I've worked around the issue by setting a flag to suppress row click, but I'd still like to know how to cancel the bubble "properly."

```
suppressHighlight = false;

this.testDataTable.onEventRowClick = function (oArgs)
{
    ...

    if (!suppressHighlight)
    {
        ...
    }
    suppressHighlight = false;
};
this.testDataTable.subscribe("rowClickEvent", this.testDataTable.onEventRowClick);

this.testDataTable.subscribe("checkboxClickEvent", function (oArgs)
{
    var elCheckbox = oArgs.target;
    var oRecord = this.getRecord(elCheckbox);
    oRecord.setData("Check", elCheckbox.checked);

    suppressHighlight = true;
});
```